# Only show the last occurrence of a loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a program which is meant to show where the last group of letters 'ing' are within a word for example if the user inputted 'sing' it would output '2'. However when I have a word like 'singing' it outputs '2' and '5'. Whereas I want it to only display the '5':

```
userinput = input('Enter a word: ')
ING = 0
while ING < len(userinput):
        ING = userinput.find('ing', ING)
        if ING == (-1):
            print('-1')
            break
        print('ing found at', ING+1)
        ING += 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userinput = input('Enter a word: ')
x = userinput.rfind('ing')+1
if x != 0:
    print(x)
```

`rfind` is a method which searches the last occurence.